# Generate an internal alarm that propagates through the thingsboard instance

Tags: thingsboard

I have a customized map widget and I allow the user to create customized geofence in the shape of a polygon. I also do some processing to determine if the latest coordinates, lat and lng fall within this polygon and output a boolean result.

I would like to be able to trigger an alarm within thingsboard that propagates into a thingsboard alarm widget.

Currently I have tried to look into server attributes to change the state of a flag, but in the thingsboard rule chain we only have client attributes which come through and according to my reading and understanding alarms are generated within the rule chain.

How can I create an alarm from a server attribute change? Or is there any alternate option I can use

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out by using the server attribute and then checking the attribute updated messages from the input node and then generating an alarm based on some check of the state of my server attribute.